# Manipulating rows and columns in HTML table with multi-row cells

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have an html table with cells that span multiple rows:

```
  <table border="1" style=""><tbody id="x">
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">**</td>
      <td>AAAA</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row2">
      <td>BBBB</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>CCCC</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="ee">EEEE</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="dd">DDDD</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert ("index of dd before delete =" + document.getElementById("dd").cellIndex);
  document.getElementById("row2").style.display="none";
  alert ("index of dd after delete =" + document.getElementById("dd").cellIndex);
</script>
```

I am trying to manipulate it in Javascript, eg hide row2.
When I do that, the multi-row cell containing "**" moves down, shifting all the cells in row 3 by 1 to the right. Evidently I have to reduce its rowSpan. 
But it seems when I am looking at row 1, I have no way of knowing that there is a multi-row cell intersecting this row - it seems I have to scan all the rows above row2 for multi-row cells.

Is there a better/quicker way to find out what multi-row cells affect the hiding (or deleting) operation?

Comment: `tr` elements don't handle `display:none` well. You should set `visibility:collapse` instead. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/tables.html#dynamic-effects

Comment: Mr Lister's solution works properly in FF only. `display` works in IE, but Chrome and Opera seems not to work neither with `display` nor `visibility`.

Comment: Thanks guys; I tried visibility, but in IE this just displays blank rows. I am looking to target IE initially, then worry about others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using javascript... It is working properly.

Change the value of `currRowToDelete` for Range `[1 to 6]`.

[Refer for working code: http://jsfiddle.net/arunkumrsingh/cdS2D/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/arunkumrsingh/cdS2D/1/)

```
<table id="tbl" border="1" runat="server" >
   <tr id="row1">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row2">
      <td rowspan="3">**</td>
      <td>AAAA</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row3">
      <td>BBBB</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row4">
      <td>CCCC</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row5">
      <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="ee">EEEE</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="row6">
      <td style="">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="dd">DDDD</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
  </table>


<script type="text/javascript">
var trs = document.getElementById("tbl").getElementsByTagName("tr");
var tds;
var bDeleted = false;
var currRowToDelete = 3;

for(var i=0;i<currRowToDelete;i++)
{   
    tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var j=0;j<tds.length;j++)
    {   
        var currRowSpan = tds[j].rowSpan;       
        if(currRowSpan > 1)       
        {           
            if(eval(i + 1) == currRowToDelete)
            {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");                        
                cell.innerHTML = tds[j].innerHTML;            
                trs[i + 1].insertBefore(cell, trs[i + 1].getElementsByTagName('td')[0]);                
                document.getElementById("tbl").deleteRow(i);
                bDeleted = true;
                document.getElementById("tbl").rows[i].cells[0].rowSpan = eval(currRowSpan -1);                
            }
            else
            {   
                if(eval(currRowSpan + i) >= currRowToDelete)
                    document.getElementById("tbl").rows[i].cells[0].rowSpan = eval(currRowSpan -1);             
            }
        }        
    }
}
if(bDeleted == false)
    document.getElementById("tbl").deleteRow(currRowToDelete -1);
</script>
```

Comment: Sergei Veinberg - Have you tried the above JS code? Is this helpful?

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution, in which you don't have to calculate the `Rowspan` and `Colspan`.

Step 1: Get the content of HTML (As mentioned above) and save as `EXCEL` file.

[image]

Step 2: Delete the particular Row (ie `Row 2`).

[image]

Step 3: Save as `HTML` file and Read the HTML content.

You will get the HTML in correct format.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to delete a row in Javascript, otherwise I could simply re-render the table.